# Any idea to solve this error "NameError: global name 'string' is not defined" python

Tags: python

I'm trying to call  recommendation model from flask, so i want return a response for to consume by another application (java).

```
def get_recomendation(strRange1,strRange2,top):

        recomendacion = loaded_model.recommend(users=range(strRange1,strRange1),k=top)

         #string = str(reco)
         #print type(string)
        global string    

        for reco in recomendacion:
            string += str(reco)

        return string
```

Comment: Please fix your title and add a description of the problem.

Comment: instead of creating strings in a loop use `''.join(map(str, recommendations))`

Comment: Your code still isn't formatted properly. And we need more information on what your doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
global string
```

does not automatically assign an empty string to the variable `string`. It simply allows the variable to be written to the global scope from within the function. So when you say:

```
string += str(reco)
```

Python expands it into:

```
string = string + str(reco)
```

but it doesn't know what `string` on the right hand side is so it can't possibly calculate `string + str(reco)`, hence the error `'string' is not defined`.